# Why clearInterval is not working in my script?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have got a problem with my clearInterval method.
I learn about JS in depth at FrontendMasters and there is an exercise where you need to use setInterval and log a string at every second and then run clearInterval after 5 seconds. I have access to the right solution but I would like to know why my solution is not working to get better understanding. The `console.log('clear called', func);` runs after 5 seconds and log the `clear called` string and the function body. I have tried to use setTimeout to wrap `wrapper.stop()` but it did not work that way either. I have used closures to try to solve the exercise. Here is my script.

```
function sayHowdy() {
 console.log('Howdy');
}


function everyXsecsForYsecs(func, interval, totalTime) {
 function clear() {
   console.log('clear called', func);
   clearInterval(func);
 }
 return {
   start() {
     setInterval(func, interval);
   },
   stop() {
     setTimeout(clear, totalTime);
   }
 }
}


const wrapper = everyXsecsForYsecs(sayHowdy, 1000, 5000);
wrapper.start();
wrapper.stop();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clearInterval` does not take a function but a *timer id* which gets returned when using `setInterval` (so that you can set multiple timers onto the same function, and cancel them individually). To use that, declare a local variable inside `everyXsecsForYsecs`

```
  var timer;
```

Then assign the timer to it:

```
 timer = setInterval(func, interval);
```

Then you can `clearInterval(timer)`.

Comment: I have updated the script and it works now. I was not aware that I can not use function in `clearInterval` method but I have to declare a variable and assign the `setInterval` method to it.